# Why can't I use '=' after define in a GNU makefile? The docs suggest I can

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to use `define` in GNU make. Running make on this test Makefile echoes "dummy":

```
define FOO =
$$(error foo $(1))
endef

$(eval $(call FOO,bar))

all:
    @echo dummy
```

If I remove the `=`, then it errors with `foo bar` as I intended.

The GNU make manual has all the define examples using the form with the equals sign present. Why does that seem to be ignored for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`define` with assignment was introduced in GNU Make 3.82, most likely that you're using an older version.

However, in the recent version `define foo =` is the same as plain `define foo`, just use the latter to get it work with pre-3.82 versions.